# Insert data into child table given name of master

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables with 1...0.n relation:

```
--drop table if exists child;
--drop table if exists master;

create table master (
  master_id serial primary key,
  master_name varchar,
  constraint unique_master unique (master_name)
  );

create table child (
  child_id serial primary key,
  master_id integer references master (master_id),
  child_name varchar
  );
```

In `master` table I have two rows:

```
insert into master (master_name) values ('master01');
insert into master (master_name) values ('master02');
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8b478/1)

Now I need to add some related rows for `master01` into `child` table. I have only string `master01` as input, not `master_id`. I have a solution using `cross join`:

```
insert into child (master_id, child_name)
select 
  master_id, child_name
from
  (select master_id from master where master_name = 'master01') as master_data
  cross join (
    values 
      ('child01'),
      ('child02'),
      ('child03')
      ) child_data (child_name);
```

This works, but I feel like there should be something easier. What other options I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the cross join

```
insert into child (master_id, child_name)
select 
    (select master_id from master where master_name = 'master01'),
    child_name
from (values 
    ('child01'),
    ('child02'),
    ('child03')
) child_data (child_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [pgScript](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/dev/pgscript.html):

```
SET @MN = select master_id from master where master_name = 'master01';

insert into child (master_id, child_name) values 
    (@MN, 'child01'),
    (@MN, 'child02'),
    (@MN, 'child03')
```

Comment: Do you think that in my query the subselect will be evaluated for each row? Did you test it? I guess it will be evaluated only once and so it will behave exactly as your script. Why introduce a dependency?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto You provided perfect answer to my question and that's the reason why it is accepted. Using pgScript just simplified my script which is much more complex than example in my question a lot. As I am the only user of the script and it's running on my desktop only and I am using pgAdmin all the time, I do not mind introducing such dependency.